# Sublime Text shortcut for abstracting plan text to i18n tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, sublimetext3, sublimetext, rails-i18n

This may be too specific for stackoverflow, but perhaps others will find this useful.

I'm working on internationalising my Rails app. I'm using Sublime Text 3.

In my views, let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<p> Hello World </p>
```

... and I want to quickly change it to:

```
<p> <%= t '.hello_world' %> </p>
```

Is there a way to use Sublime Text macros to achieve this? Basically what I want is to highlight some text, and run a command that:

1. converts that text to snake case
2. appends with a dot (.)
3. wraps in single quotation marks
4. add a t-space
5. wraps in Rails alligator brackets (<%= %>)

Comment: Other than creating a custom package in Python to do that, I don't think this is something Sublime Text can do by itself.

Answer (score 0):

While I couldn't figure how to do exactly what I asked above, I did find a helpful Sublime Text package called [Rails I18n Helper](https://github.com/Adeptus/rails-i18n-helper) that got me nearly there.